# Using php call_user_func to reduce redundancy in code

Tags: rest, laravel, controller

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to create a REST API. I have 50+ resources that I need to return in JSON, so for each of my resources the controllers look something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $holdingAccounts = HldAcc::all();

    return response()->json(['HldAccs' => $holdingAccounts]);
}
```

And then some other similar functions like store, create, destroy, update and so on.

The same exact functions are in all other controllers with the difference being the resource name.

So I came up with an idea to use the `call_user_func` PHP method. So I made a parent class called `ResourceController` and had all my resources extend it instead of directly extending the `Controller` class. Within the Controller class I do the following:

```
class ResourceController extends Controller
{
        private $className;

        public function setClassName($className)
        {
            $this->className = 'App\Models\\' . $className;
        }

        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $resource = call_user_func(array($this->className, 'all'));

            return response()->json($resource);
        } 

// and the rest of the methods go similarly...
```

and from within my HldAcc I do:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    parent::setClassName('HldAcc');
    return parent::index($request);
}
```

This may not sound like much code reduction, but with the rest of the methods and the other resources it does save a lot.

Now my question is: I hear everywhere that `call_user_func()` is bad performance-wise. Is that true? If so, what do you guys suggest I do instead?

Comment: It looks like in your case you could use the DB facade and the table would be determined based on class name, this would eliminate the need for call_user_func. But I'm not sure how this code is better, in my opinion it's not for few reasons

Comment: IMO you won't notice any performance impact by using call_user_func. The amount of logic that the framework and the called method will need to execute will be magnitudes larger than the overhead you might get from using call_user_func. Why not just test it? Try it both ways multiple times and compare the averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to work with class names as strings, as you got the full power of the laravel IoC for you.

What I recommend you to do is to create a base controller that provide the methods you want on ANY model:

```
class BaseEntityController {
    private $model;
    private $jsonName;
    public function __construct(Model $model, $jsonName) {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->jsonName = $jsonName;
    }

    public function index(Request $request) {
         $data = $this->model->all();
         return response()->json([$this->jsonName => $data ]);
    }

    /* Many other functions that do fun things */
}
```

And then, all you have to do is to create subclass of this controller, and use laravel IoC to inject the correct model using typehinting.

Your others controllers will be as slim as

```
class HldAccController extends BaseEntityController {
    public function __construct(HldAcc $model) {
        parent::__construct($model, 'HldAcc');
    }
}
```

Laravel will create HldAccController, automaticaly injecting the HldAcc model, which will provide the correct all() implementation to the BaseEntityController to do his work.

Also to answer your specific question, the performance penalty of using `call_user_func` is negligible. It's not the most optimised code ever. But I don't think it'll be the bottleneck compared to the cost of laravel's startup or db calls.

Answer (score 0):

@Atrakeur's answer or using the DB facade and passing it variable strings for the table name would both work to achieve what you are looking for by creating a parent controller.

However, I'd like to suggest an alternative approach. What you are doing is simply calling the `::all()` method on every resource. I think you might want to think about the pros of doing it this way:

You can define a route as such:

```
Route::get('/api/search/{entity}', 'SearchController@getAll');
```

Then, in your controller your `index` method would be:

```
public function getAll($entity)
{
    return DB::table($entity)->all();
}
```

That could potentially be it.. But what about if you don't want every resource to be accessible, or if you want to be able to pass a more readable string through the URL rather than your table name? Well then I think your controller could look like this:

```
protected $permittedResources = [
    'hold-account' => 'hld_acc'
];

public function getAll($entity)
{
    if (isset($this->permittedResources[$entity])) {
        return DB::table($this->permittedResources[$entity])->all();
    }

    // otherwise throw some exception or redirect someplace fun
}
```

With this approach you allow for a single small controller while having readable URL's, a way to choose which resources are permitted, a way to choose what happens when a resource is not permitted, and an easy way to extend the controller to contain other types of searches you may need for example.

PS as others have mentioned its not really a big deal to use call_user_func.

Answer (score 0):

I believe doing it @Atrakeur's way is the best way. But had worked around it before I could see the answers here. So here is my solution anyway:

I created a base controller class called `Resource_Controller` and have all the resource controllers extend it.

To have this class functioning I had to change the naming convention for the controller names; calling them `<resourcename>_controller`, because, well, the solution depends on the controller's name.

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Resource_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // the get_class($this) method returns the child class name that was called
        // the str_replace method removes the 'App\Http\Controllers\' prefix leaving oly the class name
        $childClassName = str_replace('App\Http\Controllers\\', '', get_class($this));

        // the explode method slices the string using the '_' as a delimiter and returns an array with two or more substrings
        // for example Ctlg_Controller is returned as ['Post', 'Controller']
        $word = explode('_', $childClassName);

        // class names will either contain 2 parts or 3 parts
        // for example 'Post_Controller' or 'Post_Comment_Controller'
        $wordCount = count($word);

        // in case the class name is something like 'Post_Controller'
        if ($wordCount == 2)
        {
            // get the complete model class name. for example: 'App\Models\Post'
            $resourceName = 'App\Models\\' . $word[0];

            // remove the 'App\Models\' at the beginning and an 's' at the end.
            // to get something like 'Posts'
            $shortResourceName = str_replace('App\Models\\', '', $resourceName) . 's';

            // use the resourceName to query all rows in the database. this should evaluate to something
            // like App\Models\Ctlg::all()
            $resource = $resourceName::all();   
        }
        // in case the class name is something like 'Post_Comment_Controller'
        elseif ($wordCount == 3)
        {
            // get the complete first model class name. for example: 'App\Models\Post'
            $parentResourceName = 'App\Models\\' . $word[0];

            // remove the 'App\Models\' at the beginning. to get something like 'Post'
            $shortParentResourceName = str_replace('App\Models\\', '', $parentResourceName);

            // get the complete second model class name. for example: 'App\Models\Comment'
            $resourceName = 'App\Models\\' . $word[1];

            // remove the 'App\Models\' at the beginning.
            // and adds an 's' at the end
            // to get something like 'Comments'
            $shortResourceName = str_replace('App\Models\\', '', $resourceName) . 's';

            // find a record in table $parentResourceName (for example 'Post')
            // using id provided in the URL {$shortParentResourceName}
            // the final statement should evaluate to something like
            // like App\Models\Post::find($request->Post)
            $parentResource = $parentResourceName::find($request->{$shortParentResourceName});

            // should evaluate to something like: $parentResource->Comments;
            $resource = $parentResource->{$shortResourceName};   
        }

        return response()->json([$shortResourceName => $resource]);
    }
}
```

I still did not implement the rest of the REST functions like the store, update, etc... Not sure if I'll keep using this way, but if I do I'll update this answer with any changes I make.